# Unexpected token error in JS function

Tags: javascript

I am trying to run this code but it's giving me unexpected token
 error. please help solving this error

```
var goSleep=function();// goSleep Function
{
    var count=0;
    var loop=false;
    while(count<3) //while loop
    {
        console.log("hi!");
        count++;
        loop=false;
    }
    for(i=0;i<4;i++) //for loop
    {
        console.log(i);
    }
    var login=false;
    do{//do while loop
        console.log("gud day");
    }while(login);
};
goSleep();
```

Comment: Usually a line number is given as well. Want to share that crucial information, or do we have to guess?

Comment: Obviously it should be something like `var goSleep=function() { /* code here */ };`

Comment: A semicolon after `function()`? That doesn't look right.

Comment: Based on the code snippet there is a bracket not closing (maybe the `while(count<3)`)

Comment: @TasosK. No, there is no missing bracket :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't terminate the first line with a `;`

```
var goSleep=function();// goSleep Function
// -------------------^ Remove this!!!
{
    var count=0;
    var loop=false;
    while(count<3) //while loop
    {
        console.log("hi!");
        count++;
        loop=false;
    }
    for(i=0;i<4;i++) //for loop
    {
        console.log(i);
    }
    var login=false;
    do{//do while loop
        console.log("gud day");
    }while(login);
};
goSleep();
```

Change your code to:

```
var goSleep=function() // goSleep Function
{
    var count=0;
    var loop=false;
    while(count<3) //while loop
    {
        console.log("hi!");
        count++;
        loop=false;
    }
    for(i=0;i<4;i++) //for loop
    {
        console.log(i);
    }
    var login=false;
    do{//do while loop
        console.log("gud day");
    }while(login);
};
goSleep();
```